# How do I create a new FBML/FBJS app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have a 3 year old app that was written in FBML/FBJS. I'm working on making it multiuser, so I'm creating a new app for this project. I want to use my existing codebase which uses FBML/FBJS, but I can't figure out how to enable these features from my Facebook app control panel. There no longer appears to be a "Facebook Integration" tab. Please help me figure out how to enable FBML/FBJS for my new app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **How do I create a new FBML/FBJS app?**

You **CAN'T**, back on March 11, 2011 no new FBML/FBJS applications are allowed, please check the Facebook [Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) and this blog [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462#fbml_roadmap).

Answer (score 0):

Since FBML/FBJS have been abandoned you can use the Facebook JS SDK to create your app.  It is easy to implement.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Here is a working example: 
http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/

Comment: is the SDK backwards compatible with FBJS? It didn't appear to be, and I was hoping that I wouldn't have to rewrite my extensive FBJS codebase. Thanks.